# selinux user_u staff_u .bash_profile permission denied on ssh login

Tags: ssh, rhel, selinux, administration

A security rule states

***RHEL** must prevent non-privileged users from executing privileged functions, including disabling, circumventing, or altering implemented security safeguards/countermeasures.*

> All administrators must be mapped to the "sysadm_u", "staff_u", or an appropriately tailored confined role as defined by the organization.
>
> All authorized non-administrative users must be mapped to the "user_u" role.
>
> semanage -a -s <user_u | staff_u | sysadm_u> <.username>

If I map my local account, which is defined in `/etc/passwd` and is in the `users` group (gid=100) as well as in the `wheel` group, the following happens:

- mapped as **user_u** I get `.bash_profile permission` defined in putty window after logging in
- mapped as **staff_u** I get `.bash_profile permission` defined in putty window after logging in
- mapped as **sysadm_u** I do not get the permission denied; I also have to `setsebool ssh_sysadm_login on` in order to ssh in when mapped to sysadm_u.

My main question is

1. why the permission denied on `.bash_profile` ?

Tangental questions:

2. I will have regular users as `user_u` for which this is a problem, but for *admins* which should be used `staff_u` or `sysadm_u` ?
3. What is the difference in laymens terms of `staff_u` and `sysadm_u` ?  The redhat article https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/managing-confined-and-unconfined-users_using-selinux mentiones **Additional Roles** what does this mean is seems `staff_u` is the same as `sysadm_u` ?
4. What is best practice if I *admin* accounts, which by default will be in the `wheel` group, that I just want to allow `sudo -i` use how then should selinux be used?  Right now based on the provided instruction I have to go on this is dysfunctional.